# General form of the Lorentz Transformation

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

My textbook says:

> We take
>   the most general transformation relating the coordinates of a given event in the two systems to be of the form:
>
> $$x' = Ax +Bt$$
>   $$y' = y$$
>   $$z' = z $$
>   $$ t' = Cx + Dt $$

I understand why the $y'$ and $z'$ have to be the same as $y$ and $z$ and that the equations have to be linear for having same acceleration in all frames of reference, but what is the reason for the other to equations of this form to the most general form for the transformation?
Can there be any other forms?

Comment: the textbook is Kleppner and Kolenkov.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct. The most general form of the Lorentz boost is the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix} \gamma&-\gamma\beta_x&-\gamma\beta_y&-\gamma\beta_z\\ -\gamma\beta_x&1+(\gamma-1)\frac{\beta_x^2}{\beta^2}&(\gamma-1)\frac{\beta_x \beta_y}{\beta^2}&(\gamma-1)\frac{\beta_x \beta_z}{\beta^2}\\ -\gamma\beta_y&(\gamma-1)\frac{\beta_x \beta_y}{\beta^2}&1+(\gamma-1)\frac{\beta_y^2}{\beta^2}&(\gamma-1)\frac{\beta_y \beta_z}{\beta^2}\\ -\gamma\beta_z&(\gamma-1)\frac{\beta_x \beta_z}{\beta^2}&(\gamma-1)\frac{\beta_y \beta_z}{\beta^2}&1+(\gamma-1)\frac{\beta_z^2}{\beta^2}\\ \end{bmatrix}$$ where $\begin{bmatrix} \beta_x \\ \beta_y \\ \beta_z \end{bmatrix}$ is the relative velocity (divided by $c$) between the 2 frames. As JoshuaTS has rightfully pointed out, this general form is rarely used because it is convenient to choose coordinates such that relative velocity lies along the $x$-axis. In this case, the matrix reduces to the simple textbook version $$\begin{bmatrix} \gamma & -\gamma \beta & 0 & 0 \\ -\gamma \beta & \gamma & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: you have given the general form of a boost Lorentz transformation in an arbitrary direction. the most general form of a Lorentz transformation also includes a general rotation, as well as spatial and time coordinate reflections. I don't think there is a clean way to write the full general form, or at least I've never seen it done.

Comment: @ziggurism what did you mean "the most general form of a Lorentz transformation" ? Is there a transformation which is more general than the general form of the Lorentz boost in an arbitrary direction ? So what is the physical or intuitively geometric significience of such transformation ?

Comment: @PermQi yes, the most general form of a (proper orthochronous) Lorentz transformation involves _both_ a boost _and_ a rotation. So any matrix giving just a boost or just a rotation is not the most general. As far as I can tell, there isn't a clean canonical way to write the most general form, so it makes sense that most people don't. (you could just take an arbitrary boost and rotation and compose them. but combine in complicated way. see wigner rotations). But the upshot is, let's try to make sure the claims we make are correct. A pure boost alone is not the general Lorentz transformation.

Comment: More generally, the block diagonal decomposition theorem for orthogonal matrices will show that any special orthogonal $n\times n$ matrix can be decomposed into a composition of rotations in $n/2$ planes spanned by $n/2$ orthogonal pairs of vectors. In 4 dimensional Minkowski space that means that every Lorentz transformation can be written as  a composition such as a $xt$ rotation (boost) times a $yz$ rotation.

Comment: @ziggurism I deduced that every $X\in\mathfrak{so}(1,3) $ takes the form $X=\theta\cdot J+v\cdot K$, where $\theta,\,v\in\mathbb R^3 $ and $J=J_1+J_2+J_3,\ K=K_1+K_2+K_3$.

Since the exponential map is bijective from $\mathfrak{so}(1,3)  $ to $SO^+(1,3)$, each Lorentz transformation $L\in SO^+(1,3)$ has the form $L=e^X$ for some $X\in\mathfrak{so}(1,3)$. The general Lorentz boost is obtained when $\theta=0 $, and hence $L=e^{v\cdot K}$. However I have no idea how to deduce that $L=e^{\psi (\widehat v\cdot K) } $ where $\tanh\psi=|v| $. How one can imply that ?

Comment: @PermQi the exponential map is not bijective. For one thing, because $\mathfrak{so}(3,1)$ is a vector space, hence contractible, whereas $SO^+(1,3)$ has nontrivial topology. Or more directly just observe that $e^{4\pi J_i}=1.$ However it is true that the exponential map is _surjective_ to the restricted Lorentz group, although that fact is not obvious, since the group is noncompact. But anyway, yes it is correct to say that a generic proper Lorentz transformation can be represented as $e^{\theta\cdot J+v\cdot K}.$

Comment: The way to prove that the scale parameter in the Lie algebra is the rapidity is the same way you show that the scale parameter of the rotation Lie algebra is the angle in radians: use the Taylor series. Just like the Pauli matrices/rotation generator satisfy $J_i^2=-1,$ which breaks the Taylor series up into sine and cosine, the boost generators satisfy $K_i^2=1$ which breaks it up into cosh and sinh. $e^{\psi K_i}=1+\psi K_i + (\psi K_i)^2/2+\cdots=\cosh\psi +( \sinh\psi) K_i$. Compare with the pure boost Lorentz matrix and you're done.

Comment: @ziggurism this is my comparison :
$$L=\exp(v\cdot K)=\exp\big(\psi(\beta\cdot K)\big) $$
so I think I have to set $v=\psi\beta=\tanh^{-1}(|\beta|)\,\beta\, $ with $|\beta|<1 $, am I right ?

Comment: I am a little confused why you have three different parameters, $v$, $\beta$, and $\psi$. If $v$ is linear velocity it should not appear in the exponential. 

I think the conclusion you should reach from $e^{\psi K}=\cosh \psi + (\sinh \psi)K=\begin{pmatrix}\gamma & -\gamma\beta\\ -\gamma\beta & \gamma\end{pmatrix}$ is that $\cosh\psi = \gamma,\sinh \psi = \beta\gamma,$ and then conclude that $\tanh\psi=\beta$.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to provide a geometrical interpretation of what's going on here, perhaps without resorting to an exact form of a Lorentz transformation! In special relativity, we are ultimately analysing the **geometry** of $\mathbb{R}^{1, 3}$ under the **Minkowski** metric. That is to say, we are looking at time dimension and space dimensions and putting them on the same footing as each other but with a measure of distance defined as 
$$ ds^ 2 =  - d t ^ 2 + d x ^ 2 + d y ^ 2 + d z ^ 2 $$ 
This means that given two 4-vectors in this space, say $ x ^ \mu $ and $ y ^ \mu $, we treat their contraction much like an inner product in Euclidean space, but instead we are computing $ x \cdot y   = \eta _{\mu \nu } x ^ \mu y ^ \nu $ where
$$ \eta_{\mu \nu } = diag(- 1 , 1 , 1, 1 ) $$
So, we have a meaningful notion of the norm of $ x $, where 
$$ x \cdot x  = x ^ \mu x ^\nu \eta_{\mu \nu } $$
Now to answer the question. A Lorentz transform is defined as a transformation **which preserves the norm of any four vector**.  So, if we do the Lorentz transform $ x ^\mu \to \Lambda ^ \mu _{ \ \ \nu}  x ^ \nu$, 
where $\Lambda $ is some matrix, it must preserve our norm for arbitrary $ x ^ \mu $, so 
$$ \Lambda ^ \mu _{ \, \, \rho } \eta ^{ \rho \sigma } \Lambda^ \nu _{\, \,  \sigma }  = \eta ^{\mu \nu}. $$ In other words, it's any member of the group $ O(3, 1 ) $, which is the space of transforms which preserve norms under the Minkowski metric.

Answer (score 0):

Your textbook is most likely saying that this is the general transformation because you can freely choose the $x$-axis to be in any direction. If the velocity of one reference frame relative to the other is $\mathbf{v}$, then you can choose the $x$-axis to lie along $\mathbf{v}$. There definitely can be more complicated transformations. Any rotation of the spacial coordinates gives a valid inertial reference frame. You can also boost along any arbitrary direction.

However, any arbitrary (continuous) Lorentz transformation can be performed by: 1) rotating the axes so that the $x$-axis lies along the direction of the boost, 2) performing the transformation from your textbook, and 3) rotating the axes again to wherever you want them to go (and translating the origin if you want). There are also discontinuous Lorentz transformations where you flip the direction of one of the spacial axes or the time axis. These transformations also give valid inertial reference frames. The most general discontinuous Lorentz transformation could be performed using a combination of the transformation from your textbook and rotations of the spacial axes.

Comment: Ok, I understand your answer but one little thing, why the particular form x' = Ax + Bt and t' = Cx + Dt ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. $x'=Ax+Bt$ and $t'=Cx+Dt$ is the most general linear transformation (as long as we exclude rotations). It has to be linear if the reference frames are inertial.